# TF51305: Either the file identification number is incorrect, or the file is missing

Tags: tfs

I get this error when I work with TFS and I want insert an image in the description box.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

solve this:

1. go Team Foundation server Administration Console
2. in Application Tier
3. in change URLs => set your server URL with IP(http://i.i.i.i) or Correct Address  (http://yourdomain.com)